# ASP.NET MVC Config File! allow debug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, web-config

I'm new to stackOverflow & MVC3 as well!

I've hosted an application and it redirect me to the errorPage (InternalError.htm): as I configured in the config file! But I want to change this settings, in order to show he error message, something like

```
line 23 : //exception Or Error here
```

can someone remind me the tag&the attribute to add ? debut=true ??? where ??? etc.
kind regards !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"` and you will see errors if you are on your local computer

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/system/Error/FriendlyError">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/system/Error/accessDenied" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I want. I want to see the syntaxe error 'ONLINE' something like: line 23 : //exception Or Error here

Comment: Also, check out ELMAH: http://code.google.com/p/elmah/ it's a simple to use error logger, and you can install it directly from the Nuget package: http://nuget.org/packages/elmah/

Answer (score 1):

I used a custom error handler.

Add the following code to the **Global.asax.cs**:

```
    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        // if the debugger is attached, do not show the custom error page
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
            RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values["controller"] = "MyCustomErrorController";
            routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";
            routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;

            IController errorsController = new MyCustomErrorController();
            var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
            errorsController.Execute(rc);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // if an error occurs within this method, do nothing
            // app will automatically show the browser's default error page
        }
    }
```

I also added custom code to my error page to show the exception details if the user is a super user. So if I'm not in debug mode or on the live site, I can easily see the error details (if I'm logged in as the admin).

To better understand the code, google or step through it using the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the customErrors attribute ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx)).

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="url"
              mode="On|Off|RemoteOnly">
     <error. . ./>
</customErrors>
```

On a local development machine you can set it to `Off` or `RemoteOnly`. On your production machine you set it to `On` or `RemoteOnly`.

In your case, if it's set to `RemoteOnly` you can see the exception details when you remote desktop to the production machine. If that's not possible just switch it to `Off`.

Comment: what about detailed error as in local ?

line 23 : //exception Or Error here

Comment: Are you deploying a debug or release version?

Comment: Sorry Wouter, I no longer understand what the RELEASE Or the DEBUG version is!
I have developped a asp.net mvc3 application and I right-clicked and I have chosen the the publish/deploy tab. but I want to trace the debug SYMBOLS online (where the app is hosted : www.mysite.com)!

Any Idea ?